# Some permission issues of Django 1.10.1

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-allauth

```
@login_required
def some_view(request):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return render(request, 'article/column/article_column.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'blog/titles.html')
```

How to make some websites accessible only by super users not directly accessed by other users (such as http://127.0.0.1:8000/article/article-column/).

Please give me the available code. I am a rookie, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

create only models and register in admin.py  that's it, then you can access admin modules